# The process debug port is already in use! - Process Debug - Android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, adb

This warning occurs during `Eclipse/Android` development when I want to pin the `debugger` to the `process`.

[image]

And this is an output:

[image]

The `device` process and `debug bridge` has been restarted several times with no result.

`Console` output:

```
Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger
Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger
Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger
Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger
Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger
Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue. Only solution I could find:

Reboot the device...

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect the device from the system and restart eclipse. Connect the device again. This worked for me.